# Embed <script> through jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append a twitter script along with some HTML via a for each loop. The loop forks fine, until I add the `<script>` tags at the end. What I'm trying to do is have jQuery spit out my data and then put a twitter tweet button below the information.

I'm wondering if there's another way to get jQuery to append the script to my `#entries` div.

My code is below:

```
$.each(data.Entries, function(entriesIndex, entriesObject) {

    if (entriesObject.Field21 == "Yes") {

        if (entriesObject.Field15 == "Yes") {

            $("<li />", {
                html: '<p><a href="http://twitter.com/share">foo</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></p>'


                // Add it to the page
            }).appendTo("#entries");

        } // end if entry = yes
    } // end if approved = yes

}); // end for each loop
```

*update*

Looks like it puts the script on the page but does not fire - not super familiar with how the twitter script works, but wondering if you guys could help! Thanks!

See an example page here: http://bostonwebsitemakeover.com/vote.html

```
    $.each(data.Entries, function(entriesIndex, entriesObject) {

        var p, tweet; // oh hey look, variables!

        if (entriesObject.Field21 == "Yes") {

            if (entriesObject.Field15 == "Yes") {

                     p = $("<p />", {
                    html: "<p>" + '<a href="' + entriesObject.Field19 + '" target="_blank">' + entriesObject.Field4  +  "</p>" + '<img src="http://images.websnapr.com/?url=' + entriesObject.Field19 + '" />' + "</a>"
                    });

                     tweet = $('<script>').attr({
                        type: 'text/javascript',
                        src: 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'

                    });

            } // end if entry = yes

        } // end if approved = yes


        $('<li class="entry">').append(p).append(tweet).appendTo('#entries');

}); // end for each loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('<script>').attr({
  type: 'text/javascript',
  src: 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'
}).appendTo('#entries');
```

I think will do the trick. Also, try to use the .attr, .text, etc. parameters when using jQuery to insert code. Makes it a little more stable, and semi-protects you from XSS.

**EDIT** <strike>Actually, interestingly enough, I think this is referrer-inhibited. I can't seem to get it to import, even on jsfiddle, yet I can direct-access it. I'm looking in to it though...</strike>
Nevermind, seems to load, just doesn't show up in Google chrome/firebug DOM tree (yet chrome shows it loading in resources timeline).

Comment: @nikibrown: I'm not sure what you're expecting from this script file, placing `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>` directly in the page body has no result. Is this supposed to auto-generate content, or just a library to make calling twitter API easier? (I've also tried variations, such as [`.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) with no luck)

Comment: bah... forgot to put the link with the data atributes - the twitter script grabs that link and spits out a tweet button.

Answer (score 1):

**edit** 
Wow, ignore me. I didn't read through your question well enough. The script is obviously not yours, since it is located on twitter.com haha. I'm sorry.

---

Is the tweet button's script what's being loaded in the widget.js script? If so, is it a custom script that you wrote? I ask because you could modify the click handler of the button to instead be `live()`, and then pass the string 'click' and the function you want for the handler. That would attach the handler to each button when it's added to the page dynamically.

Comment: hmm that sounds 'advanced' :) Its just the standar twitter 'tweet' button http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your <a> is missing the class "twitter-share-button"

I think from the look of it that the script looks for links with that class and generates the button and tweet count (actually an iframe)

I would have thought you need only load the script once on the page, but it may not handle links built dynamically by javascript

**Edit** http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button_faq#multiple-buttons definitely says to load the script only once